# F#: Mutually recursive type definitions with custom equality operators

Tags: f#, equality, discriminated-union

I'm trying to create a set of types which should have equality defined for comparison with each-other.

I got this far without a problem:

```
[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]
type Foo = Foo of string
    with
        override x.Equals (y : obj) =
            match y with
            | :? Foo y' ->
                match x with
                | Foo x' -> transform x' = transform y'
            | :? Bar y' ->
                match x with
                | Foo x' -> transform x' = transform y'
            | _ -> false

        // x.GetHashCode omitted for brevity

and [<CustomEquality; NoComparison>] Bar = Bar of String
    // similar definitions here
```

However, this doesn't seem to let me compare them. For example, this code fails to compile:

```
let foos : Foo list = getFoos ()
let bar : Bar = getBar ()
foos |> List.exists (fun f -> f = bar)
```

complaining that a list of `Bar`s was expected in place of `foos : Foo list`. If I change the anonymous function to `(fun (f : Foo) -> f = bar)`, the compiler instead complains that it expected a `Foo` in place of `bar : Bar`.

Is there a way to implement cross-type equality like this? Does the requirement that they are all singly-cased type unions with the same underlying type make it easier?

---

<sup>Footnote: Yes, I realize this might not be a good idea, but I want to try it and see how well it would suit my needs. My ultimate goal is to create types that cannot be passed in place of each-other, but that still allow for equality comparison and without creating a wrapping type union - other suggestions are welcome :)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried `fun f -> f.Equals bar`?